# Link on a DIV but not on content

Tags: html, css

I set a link on a `<div>` but all the elements of the `<div>`become also links.
Any clue how I could remove the formatting from the children?

[image]

The bottom `<div>` is on rollover mode.

```css
div.hotel-preview {
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

div.hotel-preview:hover {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<a href="@Url.Action("Hotel", "Home", new { id = hotel.IdHotel})">
  <div class="hotel-preview">
    ...
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: `text-decoration:none` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `text-decoration: none` to `<a>`, like:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
div.hotel-preview {
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

div.hotel-preview:hover {
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="@Url.Action("Hotel", "Home", new { id = hotel.IdHotel})">
  <div class="hotel-preview">
    ...
  </div>
</a>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Worked thanks. I used div > a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}

Comment: It's my pleasure @PierreA. Please accept this answer if this helped you out.

Comment: @Saurav Rastogi  will do, have to wait 5 minutes to accept any answer

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to remove the underlines for the hyperlinks, you can just add `text-decoration: none;` to your  tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    div.hotel-preview {
      border-style: solid;
      padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
      margin-bottom:20px;
    }

    div.hotel-preview:hover {
      background-color: aliceblue;
    }
    
    .href-wrapper {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <a class="href-wrapper" href="/">
     <div class="hotel-preview">
       <h1>Matterhorn</h1>
       
       <p>Lieu: Brig</p>
       <h4>Contact</h4>
       <p>+41279220001</p>
       <p>info@matterhorn.ch</p>
     </div>
  </a>
  
</body>
</html>
```